# How to extract zip file in remote host

Tags: ftp, zip, visual-studio-code, filezilla, unzip

I'm looking for a way to extract zip files on the remote FTP host from my own computer.

I tried both *Filezilla* and Liximomo's Sftp extension in Vscode. Both are working nicely and I can download/upload/delete files, but found no option to extract `.zip`.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot extract ZIP file using SFTP (nor FTP – your question is ambiguous regarding the protocol you are using). Is does not matter what client or extension you are using.

You have use a shell command for that (there are for sure VS Code extensions for that too).

See also [How to unzip files via an FTP connection?](https://superuser.com/q/479661/213663)